Power BI Measure to Filter on Column A based on value in Column B from another table
I have two tables - table A with customer, sales-id, sales-part and sales. table B with sales-part and identifier (Y/N). I need a measure to filter for sales-id when sales-part has identifier=Y. table A and table B have many to 1 relationship.
My output should have data for entire sales-id if a sales-part has identifier=Y.
I tried building a measure with if condition within Calculate and filter but won't work.
Thanks for your help in advance!
Table A and table B are attached as images
enter image description here
enter image description here
My output should have data for entire sales-id if a sales-part has identifier=Y.
enter image description here

I added calculated column in Table A:
YIdentifier = 
VAR CurrentSalesID = 'Table A'[salesid]
VAR IdentifierYCount = 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Table A'),
        FILTER(
            'Table A',
            'Table A'[salesid] = CurrentSalesID &&
            RELATED('Table B'[identifier]) = "Y"
        )
    )
RETURN
IF(IdentifierYCount > 0, "Y", "N")

The result is:

When you use this column as a slicer, you get both rows, even tho in Table B identifier for salespart s2 is N.


This is good, thank you. Can this be accomplished using a measure?

I tried other methods to achieve this, but all included adding either calculated column, or calculated table. I couldn't succeed using only a measure.
